# Keep them and it will pay

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Pay them and they will stay. **Keep them and it will pay**.” Sudanese mathematician Mohamed Hassan’s summary of Nature’s first international survey tracking scientists’ salaries and how they feel about their jobs in 2010 was both pithy and prescient.
> Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-03049-6)

Does "Keep them and it will pay" mean "Keep them and it will be worthy of the money spent, the time, the efforts etc."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context "*it will pay*" mainly means *it is worth the effort to keep them*. Alternatively, it means *to be punished* or *to be rewarded*.

So you can read it in these couple of ways:

1. Pay them and they will stay. Keep them and **it will be worth the
   effort.**
2. Pay them and they will stay. Keep them and **you will get rewarded.**
3. Pay them and they will stay. Keep them and **you will get punished.**

For the meaning of "it pays" i can also quote this from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%20pays)

> **it pays**:
> used to say that doing something is worth the effort or
> expense

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the missing verbs.

Comment: "Keep them and you will get punished" is clearly not what's meant here.

Comment: Also, #1 should read "Keep them and it will **be** worth the effort."

Comment: In this context, it can never mean "**you** will get punished". For "pay" to have the meaning of "be punished", "you" must be the subject, as in, "You will pay". Here, "it will pay" *could* mean, "Keeping them will be punished", but it's nonsense to punish "keeping them" rather than punishing a person, so nobody will understand it this way